# Show Window Account User's full name in report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to display the full username in my SSRS report. I used `=User!UserID` which gives domain\login.

Can I get the full name of the user like Tom,Cruise, instead of abc\tcruise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global variable you mentioned (`User!UserID`) is the only relevant built in variable, if you look at the [built-in globals on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), so I think you may have already answered your own question.

Some alternatives from the top of my head:

- If you're running the report in your own app using the *ReportViewer*, you could use a hidden parameter and have the app pass the full user name.
- A more heavy weight alternative you could try is using [custom (embedded) code or assembly references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238%28v=sql.105%29), that may give you access to this info (not 100% sure though).